# Can someone confirm if my code satisfies these questions?

Tags: python-cryptography

Use the
crytographic objects (AESCrypto and RSACrypto)

1. Install necessary cryptographic module(s).
2. Verify the hash of the supplied part 1 files (publickey.pem, part1.txt.enc, part1.txt.sig)
   with their hashes (part1.sha256).
3. Decrypt the encrypted text file (part1.txt.enc) using AES-128. The key is sfhaCS2023
4. Verify the plaintext using the provided signature and public key (part1.txt.sig, publickey.pem)

```
import random
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15

# Define AES class
class AESCrypto:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key.encode('utf-8')

    def encrypt(self, cleartext):
        Block_Size = AES.block_size
        pad = lambda s: s + (Block_Size - len(s) % Block_Size) * chr(Block_Size - len(s) % Block_Size)
        cleartext_blocks = pad(cleartext)

        iv = random.new().read(Block_Size)
        crypto = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(iv + crypto.encrypt(cleartext_blocks.encode()))

    def decrypt(self, enctext):
        enctext = base64.b64decode(enctext)
        iv = enctext[:16]
        crypto = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[-1])]
        return unpad(crypto.decrypt(enctext[16:]))

# Verify the hash of files
def verify_file_hash(filename, expected_hash):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            file_hash = hashlib.sha256(file.read()).hexdigest()
        return file_hash == expected_hash
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return False

# Decrypt using AES-128
def decrypt_aes(file_path, key):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            encrypted_data = base64.b64decode(file.read())
        aes = AESCrypto(key)
        decrypted_data = aes.decrypt(encrypted_data)
        return decrypted_data.decode('utf-8')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None

# Verify plaintext using RSA signature
def verify_rsa_signature(plaintext, signature_path, public_key_path):
    try:
        with open(public_key_path, 'rb') as public_key_file:
            public_key = RSA.import_key(public_key_file.read())
        with open(signature_path, 'rb') as signature_file:
            signature = signature_file.read()
        h = SHA256.new(plaintext.encode('utf-8'))
        pkcs1_15.new(public_key).verify(h, signature)
        return True
    except (ValueError, TypeError, FileNotFoundError):
        return False

# Verify hash
part1_hash = None
try:
    with open("part1.sha256", 'r') as hash_file:
        part1_hash = hash_file.read().strip()
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

if part1_hash and \
   verify_file_hash("publickey.pem", part1_hash) and \
   verify_file_hash("part1.txt.enc", part1_hash) and \
   verify_file_hash("part1.txt.sig", part1_hash):
    print("File hashes verified successfully.")
else:
    print("File hashes do not match or some files are missing.")

# Decrypt the encrypted text file
decrypted_text = decrypt_aes("part1.txt.enc", "sfhaCS2023")
if decrypted_text is not None:
    print("Decrypted text:", decrypted_text)
    # Verify the plaintext using RSA signature
    if verify_rsa_signature(decrypted_text, "part1.txt.sig", "publickey.pem"):
        print("RSA verified successfully.")
    else:
        print("RSA verification failed.")
else:
    print("Failed to decrypt the file.")
```